# Unity: How to animate a flashing TextMesh (so varying the alpha when the player does something)?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have tried retracing the steps from the survival shooter tutorial (create an animation clip on the property of the TextMesh, vary the alpha, and create a state machine), but animating the alpha property in the textMesh.MeshRenderer._Color object does nothing, because this object disappears on runtime (even though the animator window accepts it as a valid object to animate...), and my animation window actually shows the object is missing when I reopen it--so I am thinking that this must be some kind of throwaway color object?

The problem is that this is the only "color" that I can edit in the Text Mesh object.  Otherwise, the state machine is working perfectly; and the animation seems to be playing...Just nothing is happening...and, like I said, when I reopen the animation clip in the animation window, the property is labeled as 'missing,' even though I have not touched the respective object.

Coming back to what I am trying to do: I am trying to implement a flashing label in the game (rather than on the HUD) that is invisible until the player gets close, whereupon it starts slowly flashing (it is a control suggestion). Maybe the Textmesh object is the wrong object; maybe my animation process is wrong...but I think the easier answer might be to go into how to implement what I am trying to do...rather than trouble shoot the mistake I am making...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with animation and through code. I would go with code. With `Coroutines`, `lerp` and `Time.deltaTime` almost any type of animation is possible in Unity. The code below will blink TextMesh when `startTextMeshAnimation()` is called and continue until `stopTextMeshAnimation()` is called. You change the speed by calling `changeTextMeshAnimationSpeed()` and passing in the speed value. This is in seconds. **0.2** to **5f** is fine.

```
public TextMesh textMesh;
public float animSpeedInSec = 1f;
bool keepAnimating = false;

private IEnumerator anim()
{

    Color currentColor = textMesh.color;

    Color invisibleColor = textMesh.color;
    invisibleColor.a = 0; //Set Alpha to 0

    float oldAnimSpeedInSec = animSpeedInSec;
    float counter = 0;
    while (keepAnimating)
    {
        //Hide Slowly
        while (counter < oldAnimSpeedInSec)
        {
            if (!keepAnimating)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            //Reset counter when Speed is changed
            if (oldAnimSpeedInSec != animSpeedInSec)
            {
                counter = 0;
                oldAnimSpeedInSec = animSpeedInSec;
            }

            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            textMesh.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, invisibleColor, counter / oldAnimSpeedInSec);
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return null;


        //Show Slowly
        while (counter > 0)
        {
            if (!keepAnimating)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            //Reset counter when Speed is changed
            if (oldAnimSpeedInSec != animSpeedInSec)
            {
                counter = 0;
                oldAnimSpeedInSec = animSpeedInSec;
            }

            counter -= Time.deltaTime;
            textMesh.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, invisibleColor, counter / oldAnimSpeedInSec);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}

//Call to Start animation
void startTextMeshAnimation()
{
    if (keepAnimating)
    {
        return;
    }
    keepAnimating = true;
    StartCoroutine(anim());
}

//Call to Change animation Speed
void changeTextMeshAnimationSpeed(float animSpeed)
{
    animSpeedInSec = animSpeed;
}

//Call to Stop animation
void stopTextMeshAnimation()
{
    keepAnimating = false;
}`
```